# How to check if a content uri is an image or a video?

Tags: android, uri, android-storage

In my app I created a file picker that returns a list of uris like the ones below:

```
[content://media/external/file/300725, content://media/external/file/299993, content://media/external/file/299986]
```

Is there any way to know if each of these files is an image or a video?

Comment: You can check the mime type from the Uri, then use getExtensionFromMimeType method to get the file extention

Answer (score 3):

One way to do so is following [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30696106/13826785)

In short to find an image:

```
public static boolean isImageFile(String path) {
String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(path);
return mimeType != null && mimeType.startsWith("image"); }
```

To find a video:

```
public static boolean isVideoFile(String path) {
String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(path);
return mimeType != null && mimeType.startsWith("video");}
```