# Take Only ".jpg" ( Android )

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ftp, apk

I want to my application Upload only `.jpg` and not the others files with different `extensions`.

Can you tell me please what i should add to my code ?

This my code :

```
    public void jetzt() {

      FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
      try {
          ftpClient.connect(" FTP SERVER IP");

          ftpClient.setSoTimeout(10000);
          ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
          if (ftpClient.login(" LOGIN ", " PASSWORD ")) {
              ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
              ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

              ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/htdocs");

              final String serial = getManufacturerSerialNumber();
              ftpClient.makeDirectory(serial);
              ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(serial);


              final File folder = new File("mnt/sdcard/YmmyCandy");

              for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
                  try {
                      FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(fileEntry);
                      if (!fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                          String fileName = fileEntry.getName();
                          ftpClient.storeFile(fileName, fs);
                          fs.close();
                          Log.i(TAG, "sent");
                      }

                  } catch (Exception e) {
                      Log.i(TAG, "error uploading");
                  }
              }
          }
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

Comment: Please, do some research before posting a question. This duplicate was found in 10sec and this should answer your problem

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you have name of the file, you could check if it ends with .jpg (or .jpeg!):

```
    String filenameArray[] = fileEntry.getName().split("\\.");
    String extension = filenameArray[filenameArray.length-1];
    if (extension.equals("jpg") || extensions.equals("jpeg")) {...}
```

Comment: That's work ! Thank you Gudin :)

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
    ...
    String fileName = fileEntry.getName();
    ftpClient.storeFile(fileName, fs);
```

You already **have** the file name "at hand"; but instead of writing a simple check like `if (fileName.endsWith(".jpeg"))` you just upload all files!

Of course, things needs some refinement. If you exactly know that all files end in .jpeg then that works, but maybe jpg, JPG and so on should work too.

And if you want a really "complete" solution, you would have to check the [MIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589645/how-to-determine-mime-type-of-file-in-android) type of each file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer GhostCat

Comment: You are welcome: But just for the record: the answer you accepted is **overly** complex. There is no point in spliting the file name; you can just go and check the ending of that one string! And btw: you probably want to put that whole check into its **own** method, like `boolean isJpeg(String filneName)` - as that will make it easier for you to change the exact kind of check you are doing.