# MIME type for a JSON file

Tags: android, mime-types

I have a JSON file that I want to upload to Server through a Multipart request. In this process, I need to determine the MIME type of the file. I have used the following method to determine the MIME type:

```
MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(
                    fileExtension.toLowerCase());
```

For an extension of ".json", it returns a null, i.e, json is not registered with any application type.

How can I get the MIME type of a JSON file? Above API is in [the most upvoted answer on another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589645/how-to-determine-mime-type-of-file-in-android) to get the MIME type of a file. Is there any API to obtain the same correctly?

Comment: Well dont you know the mime type? Or dont you know how to get it programmatically?

Comment: Mime type should be pretty irrelevant for a server. You can use application/octet-stream for any file.

Comment: A json file is just text. So text/plain should do.

Answer (score 2):

This might be too late for you, but perhaps for future reference:

The MIME media type of JSON is `application/json`, as mentioned in this [very popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type).

Since you know and expect your files to be `.json`, you can hardcode the MIME type as `application/json.

An example in Kotlin from the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider#search):

```
private val READ_REQUEST_CODE: Int = 42

private fun performFileSearch() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)

        type = "application/json" // MIME media type
    }

    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have Apache make sure this line is in .htaccess.

AddType application/json .json

If IIS make sure that the MIME type for *.json is application/json.

Comment: This is in context of Android only!