# Xamarin File Mime Type

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I'll currently develop an Xamarin app cross platform (iOS/Android) that download a file via CrossDownloadManager and decompress the zip with SharpZipLib.Portable.

All works fine, but I want to check the download file mime type before send it to the unzip library to avoid any problem.
I cannot use the extension of file because is not required.

Comment: What are you going to do if the mime type is incorrect?   Just pass the file to the unzip library and let it make sure it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

According to Curiousity's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44672662/10374839), this is how you do it:

```
public String getMimeType(Uri uri) {
    String mimeType = null;
    if (uri.Scheme.Equals(ContentResolver.SchemeContent))
    {
        ContentResolver cr = Application.Context.ContentResolver;
        mimeType = cr.GetType(uri);
    }
    else
    {
        String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.ToString());
        mimeType = MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(
        fileExtension.ToLower());
    }
    return mimeType;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Use MimeTypes Nuget Package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MimeTypes/

You just have to pass file name to get its content-type:

```
var mimeType = MimeTypes.GetMimeType(fileName);
```

This is how I get the mime type of image picked using Image picker's FinishedPickingMedia method in Xamarin.iOS [C#]

```
NSUrl referenceURL = e.Info[new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL")] as NSUrl;
if (referenceURL != null)
{
    var fileName = referenceURL.Path.ToString();
    var url = referenceURL.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(referenceURL.ToString());
}


ALAssetsLibrary assetsLibrary = new ALAssetsLibrary();
assetsLibrary.AssetForUrl(referenceURL, delegate (ALAsset asset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation representation = asset.DefaultRepresentation;
    if (representation!= null)
    {
        string fileName = representation.Filename;
        var mimeType = MimeTypes.GetMimeType(fileName);

    }

}, delegate (NSError error) {
    Console.WriteLine("User denied access to photo Library... {0}", error);
});
```