# How to get media type or MIME type after select image/video from gallery?

Tags: android, image, video, media

Uri when select any image or video -> "content://media/external/file/34"

Comment: This is a duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589645/how-to-determine-mime-type-of-file-in-android)

Comment: While that linked-to question has lots of bad answers, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31691791/115145) is pretty good.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need Mime type from arraylist<Uri>.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below line of code

```
Uri selectedUri;
String fileextension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(selectedUri.toString());
String mimetype= MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileextension);

If(mimetype=="image/jpeg")
```

Comment: I have Uri in arraylist, so how to apply this solution?

Comment: If you are getting the list of video/image in this way using the ccontent resolver and cursor then please try below way
private val PROJECTION = arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE)
String pictureType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PROJECTION[0]))

IF NOT then try to check when you added or get in list for every item in list

Comment: Thanks. I will apply and let you know if it is working or not.